# How to show zip validation in stripe payment inline form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I am using woocomerce in wordpress .In woocomerce, for payment I am using stripe. Now I want to add zip code validation in the stripe payment from. I have read stripe documentation and found some code to show zip validation in the popup form. Here is the code I have added in the `function.php` as they mentioned in their documentation.

```
add_filter( 'wc_stripe_checkout_verify_zip','__return_true' );
```

Now problem is if I try to use inline form for stripe payment then this zip validation is not showing. Because this line of code is for showing zip in the modal.

Please help me. I am stuck from two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally after lot of searching I have done this with a plugin called [WooCommerce Stripe Payment Gateway (Credit Card, AliPay, Apple Pay)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/payment-gateway-stripe-and-woocommerce-integration/).